# Run a method in controller according to datepicker value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want run the method Index in the Home Controller according to the  date  selected in datepicker,
Here is my View code:

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker" id="calendar" />
 $("#calendar").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function (date, instance) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("Index","Home")/' + date,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert(date)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

I want when I choose a date in my datepicker run this Method:

```
 [Route("Home/{date?}")]
        public ActionResult Index( DateTime? date = null)
```

the problem is the Ajax call this URL: `Home\12-04-2018`when I choose the 12-04-2018 instead of `/Home/Index/12-04-2018` is my code wrong or am I missing something? thanks for help.

Comment: Find the `url:` line when your view is rendered and see how it has been rendered. Press F12 in the browser to inspect it.

Comment: You have defined a `[Route("Home/{date?}")]` (meaning it will not include the action name)

Comment: I comment the [Route("Home/{date?}")] It gives the same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224201/how-do-i-pass-a-datetime-value-as-a-uri-parameter-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below, this should work for you. Date has been passed as query string

Script

```
    $("#calendar").datepicker('setDate', 'today');

    $("#calendar")
        .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })
        .on("changeDate", function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("Index","Home") + '?date='+ e.date,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert(e.date)
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

And action method:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index( DateTime? date = null)
```

Update:

To change the date format in view, build new date string from date object that C# can parse

```
var newDate = e.date.getUTCMonth() + 1 + '/' + e.date.getUTCDate() + '/' + e.date.getUTCFullYear() + ' 00:00:00';
```

and pass it as parameter to controller.

Comment: I have checked it was working fine. I have used action parameter as string though. Can you check with string parameter. If it work then there may be date parsing issue.

Comment: I  added this viewbag in the Method Index  `if (date == null) { ViewBag.dt = 1; };` I got in my View : 1, means that the value didn't pass from to View to Controller.

Comment: That means action method called on date change. But date parameter was not parsed to datetime. Can you change your action parameter to string and parse it to date in action method?

Comment: Yes I did like this: `[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index( string date ) {if (date == null) { ViewBag.dt = 1; }; //code}` and I got in my View : 1.

Comment: Now you change date in required format from view before calling ajax so you can use DateTime as action parameter, or you can keep action parameter string and parse it to datetime in action method.

Comment: In ajax method, pass e.date.toISOString() instead of e.date. It should work with your datetime parameter.

Comment: Yes I passed `e.date.toISOString() instead of e.date` and in Index I tried with `string date` and `DateTime? date = null` but always the same result : I got in my View : 1 .

Comment: @M.LOOK, as i suggested you just needed to pass date in c# format from your view or you could have parsed to c# date in controller. I am updating answer how to parse date.

Comment: I tried with your solution and other solutions but it gives the same result apparently there is a problem in my Ajax code because  the debugger shows these errors: Type is not defined, Url is not defined ...

Comment: I think you could call controller method on date change, and now if you are not getting date null in action method, that should solve problem in the question. If there are other errors you should raise different question.