# Pass a datetime value from datepicker in View to Controller using Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my View I have this code:

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker" id="calendar" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#calendar")
        .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })
        .on("changeDate", function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("Index","Home")' + '?date=' + e.date.toISOString(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert(e.date)
                    }
                }
            });
    });

    $("#calendar").datepicker('setDate', 'today');

</script>
```

and I want when I change the Date in Datepicker, Ajax call the Index method:

```
     [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string date)
        {if (date == null) { ViewBag.dt = 1; };
//code
}
```

I tried many suggestion but alway I got 1 in my view means that no value passed to the Conroller, please help.

Comment: If its a date, then the parameter should be `DateTime date`, not `string`. Debug you script and check what the value of `e.date.toISOString()` returns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a method in controller according to datepicker value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837216/run-a-method-in-controller-according-to-datepicker-value)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're using wrong URL format in `url` parameter. You need to pass the datetime value from JS side as `data` parameter in AJAX call and use `Nullable<DateTime>` as action method argument:

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
    data: { date: e.date.toISOString() },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date)
{
    // other stuff
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I found that you can pass `datepicker` value using `"getDate"` argument, so that your datepicker code become like this:

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })
              .on("changeDate", function() {
                  // get date value
                  var datetime = $("#calendar").datepicker("getDate").toISOString();

                  $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
                      data: { date: datetime },
                      success: function (data) {
                      if (data.success) {
                          // do something
                      }
                  }
              });
});
```

Comment: OP's code produces the exact same result for the url (albeit your suggestion is the better way of doing it)

Comment: In controller, the parameter should be nullable `public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date==Null)`, right? (because I passed it as Datetime and I got an error.

Comment: With debugger : "datetime is not defined" and "eval at anonymous (:1:1)" what does it mean?

Comment: Try putting `datetime` declaration outside `changeDate` event, what do you get? Or what value you've got when directly use `$("#calendar").datepicker("getDate").toISOString();` in console?

Comment: always the same message "... is not defined"

Comment: Try using plain `$(this).val().toISOString();`. If `$(this)` doesn't work, use `$("#calendar")` instead. Is that `datetime` value still `undefined` after those changes?

Comment: Yes it still, I think there is something wrong with my code or I'm missing a refrence.

Answer (score 0):

try this,its working for me

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker" id="calendar" onblur="DemoEvent();"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">


      function DemoEvent() {
        alert();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("Index","Home")' + '?date=' + $("#calendar").val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert(e.date)
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    //$("#calendar").datetimepicker('setDate', 'today');
//
    window.onload = function () {
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({})
    }

</script>
    }
```

Comment: Is datapicker load in textbox?

Comment: No it doesn't just an empty alert.