# Expression for asp-route-{value}

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, datetimeoffset

```
asp-route-date="@{ DateTimeOffset.Parse(date); }"
```

Should that work? Can't find any info. Currently that somehow give me pure `date` variable value, f.e. - `...?date=01%2F02%2F2020+4%3A49+PM`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Razor expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implicit-razor-expressions) instead [Razor code blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#razor-code-blocks) so that the value will be rendered in the resulting HTML, e.g.:

Razor:

```
<a asp-action="CheckDate" asp-route-date="@DateTimeOffset.Parse(date)">check</a>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CheckDate(DateTimeOffset date)
{
    // ...
}
```

The query string in your example seems fine, as the `DateTimeOffset` object needs to be encoded to be passed to the controller. For alternative formats and further information see [How do I pass a datetime value as a URI parameter in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224201/how-do-i-pass-a-datetime-value-as-a-uri-parameter-in-asp-net-mvc).